# xamarin forms stretched views in tablets and big screens

Tags: c#, ios, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms

What is the optimal solution to design big screens and tablets?
the view looks good on phones but when on tablets or big screens, the buttons and text entries looks stretched and unprofessional.

I can add padding  but is there a better solution than that?

I see that the new pre-release of Xamarin forms version 3 doesn't support @medai. But does it account for this issue in another way?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Xamarin.Forms Page class has a `SizeChanged` event we can use to determine the available screen-size at runtime. We can adjust the UI based on the Width or Height of the screen.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
   public MainPage()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
     SizeChanged += MainPageSizeChanged;
   }

   void MainPageSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      imgMonkey.WidthRequest = Math.Min(this.Width, 400);
   }
}
```

And Xamarin.Forms provides a static `Idiom` property on the Device class that we can use to check the device type.

```
if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
{
    buttonAbout.HeightRequest = 25;
    buttonAbout.WidthRequest = 40;
}
else
{
    buttonAbout.HeightRequest = 40;
    buttonAbout.WidthRequest = 70;
}
```

Detail refer to [Adaptive UI with Xamarin.Forms](https://blog.xamarin.com/adaptive-ui-xamarin-forms/).

Comment: I used OnIdiom sometimes but it's difficult to bind every view. also, the resizing should depend on the screen size which will be different from a screen to another. Finally, resizing is a good start as well as adding padding but I was thinking of a more professional solution. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VisualStateManager to achieve this task.
Find more information on how to get started at https://xamarinhelp.com/visualstatemanager-xamarin-forms-phase-1/

Comment: I notice this upcoming feature in the next release of Xamarin forms but I still don't understand how it differs from behaviors.

Also, how to use it in this case to improve the UI of the Tablets and Big screen devices? Should I shrink the entry text? and buttons?

Isn't this same as adding padding ?